# Geonode setup to create a multi-object radial array

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: Reference Image_01]

I'm trying to build a Geonode setup that allows me to create and properly rotate a multi-object radial array in Blender 3.1.1 and I haven't found any tutorials on Youtube that can rotate the object properly like the image below below.

[image: Geometry Nodes setup]

This is a geometry nodes setup I got off Youtube. I can't animate the object properly for reasons unknown. I can anyone help or share a similar node setup to the one here?

[image: My Scene]

This is what I got after I put that node setup together. Everything's multiplying and I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you could take advantage of the 'Rotation' output of *Curve to Points*.

First locate and align instances on a Curve > Circle, and then rotate them about their (now aligned) local axes to the desired final orientation:

[image]

You could elaborate this to multiple concentric circles, scaled/rotated by index:

[image]

and mount your instances on those, also rotated by circle-index:

[image]

.. to get results more like this:

[image]